# WooCommerce woocommerce_new_order not firing when creating an order from the REST API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have the following code snippet:

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'foo_function', 10);
```

If I create a new order from the admin panel, this fires just fine.

However, creating it via the REST API will not fire the function.

Why is that?

**Update**

I've tried using the following:

`woocommerce_rest_insert_shop_object` – this one doesn't fire at all.

`wp_insert_post` and `save_post` – they *do* fire, but don't contain the line items... (on the first run, it's an empty list, and on the second run (where the $update flag is true) there is an item but that item has no data (like product id or quantity).

Comment: Have you ever tried `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` instead of `woocommerce_new_order`?

Comment: how are you doing it via rest api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add_action( "woocommerce_rest_insert_shop_order_object", 'your_prefix_on_insert_rest_api', 10, 3 );
function your_prefix_on_insert_rest_api( $object, $request, $is_creating  ) {
    if ( ! $is_creating ) {
        return;
    }

    $order_id = $object->get_id();
    $wc_order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    do_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', $order_id, $wc_order );
}
```

You have tried `woocommerce_rest_insert_shop_object`,
but the hook is `woocommerce_rest_insert_shop_order_object`

Comment: Oh wow, your solution worked. I was sure I'd also tried the correct one and it didn't work at some point... no idea what my mistake was, but your solution works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please use this hook `woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta` instead of `woocommerce_new_order` As far as I can determine, woocommerce_new_order is only fired when an order is processed through the checkout. In a lot of instances, staff were creating orders in the wp-admin and assigning them straight to processing or completed, which meant that hook wasn't doing what I thought it would. Using woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta will solve it for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't fire, either. It will fire on orders created from the admin dashboard, but not on the ones created via the REST API.

Comment: What do you need on this?

Comment: I need the hook to fire as soon as a new order arrives from whatever destination, including the REST API.

Comment: You could also try by hooking to wp_insert_post hook or save_post_{$post->post_type} which should be save_post_shop_order for shop orders.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It just seems very weird to me that woocommerce_new_order doesn't fire on every new order...

Answer (score 0):

On v2 there is the `woocommerce_rest_insert_{$this->post_type}_object` filter

So the correct hook for what you need is `woocommerce_rest_insert_shop_order_object`